# Может ли Zabbix мониторить данные в базе MySQL?

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Здравствуйте!

Мой вопрос связан с тем, что хотелось бы мониторить некоторые вычисляемые значения в базе MySQL сторонней программы. Например, необходимо мониторить в базе данных подобное значение:

```
SELECT SUM(`column1`) FROM `table` where `column2` = "text"
```

Можно ли в zabbix реализовать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 2):

Не хватает подробностей,
возможно это поможет:

[zabbix 3.0 docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/ru/manual/config/items/itemtypes/odbc_checks)

заббикс - мощный инструмент для мониторига, если у вас есть, например, готовое консольное решение(bash, python, ruby script...) для получения данных по сабжу, то внедрить в заббикс - дело времени.